# Como evitar ObjectDisposedException en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

cuando intento reabrir un formulario que se cerro desde la X de la ventana me salta la excepción `System.ObjectDisposedException` con el mensaje "No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado. Nombre del objeto: 'frm_horarios'."

Tengo entendido que la X llama al método `Dispose()`, el cual libera recursos, pero no se hasta que punto libera.
Yo controle que el formulario no sea `Null` al momento de llamarlo, pero sigue saltando esa excepción.

Codigo del formulario frm_horarios, es al que llamo:

```
public partial class frm_horarios : Form
    {
        private static Form instancia = null;  //implemento el patron singleton para tener solo una instancia de este formulario

        private frm_horarios()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static Form getFormularioHorario()
        {
            if(instancia ==null)
            {
                instancia = new frm_horarios();
                return instancia;
            }
            else
            {
                return instancia;
            }
        }
    }
```

Codigo del boton que llama al formulario frm_horarios:

```
private void btn_horarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(horario !=null)//la variable horario es del tipo Form y se encuentra declarada en el principio de la clase
            {
                horario.Show();
            }          
            else
            {
                horario = frm_horarios.getFormularioHorario();
                horario.Show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes prevenir que el cierre del formulario `frm_horarios` efectivamente deseche el objeto. Para ello, puedes agregar un evento `FormClosing`:

```
private void frm_horarios_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; // Cancelas el evento de cerrado
    this.Hide();     // Ocultas el formulario sin desecharlo
}
```

Otra manera para hacerlo sería abrir el formulario secundario como *diálogo*, con cambiar sólo una línea de tu código:

```
private void btn_horarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Con menos líneas puedes obtener el mismo resultado:
    if (horario == null)
        horario = frm_horarios.getFormularioHorario();
    horario.ShowDialog(this);
    //      ^ En lugar del método "Show", usar ShowDialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso lo solucioné agregando al Evento `Form_Closing` el `Dispose();` para lograrlo hacer en todos los formularios tengo una clase `clsFormularios` que hereda de Form con esta en el evento `Form_Closing` agregue el `Dispose()` y como todos mis formularios heredan de `clsFormularios` no tuve mas problemas.

Código hecho en vb.net

```
 Private Sub clsFormularios_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dispose() 'Destruyo el formulario.
    Close() 'Lo cierro por si queda abierto.
    Finalize()
End Sub
```